# Sort List in Custom Order in C#

Tags: c#

I need to sort a list to this order M,T,W,R,F,S,N.

M-Mon, T -Tues. W- Wed, R- Thursday, F-Friday, S-Sat. and N-Sun.

My list could be in random order W,M,F,T, etc. How do I sort it as M,W,T,F? Any efficiency way to do it?

Comment: can you share your inputs, outputs and your data structures?

Comment: For example, my input list is T, M, F and the output should be M,T,F.  (Monday, Tuesday, Friday). I would like the input list sorted in my custom order, M,T,W,R,F,S,R.

Comment: are they strings or something else?

Comment: strings only. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create and use custom comparer.

```
var items = new string[] { "W", "M", "F", "T" };

Array.Sort(items, Comparer<string>.Create(
    (x, y) =>
    {
        var keys = "MTWRFSN";
        return keys.IndexOf(x).CompareTo(keys.IndexOf(y));
    }));

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", items));
```

The same sample with List instead of Array:

```
var items = new List<string> { "W", "M", "F", "T" };

items.Sort(Comparer<string>.Create(
    (x, y) =>
    {
        var keys = "MTWRFSN";
        return keys.IndexOf(x).CompareTo(keys.IndexOf(y));
    }));

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", items));
```